# measures of sequential variation

Tags: binary-data, variability

I have psychological data that consists of series of binary choices (e.g., 1001010101) made by research subjects, where 1 and 0 reflect two different options that can be chosen.

**Are there any known measures of the variation in such sequences?**

For example, the sequence of 1s and 0s in 0101011010 is more variable than the one in 001111110.

**Edit**: to clear up any confusion in relation to the comments below, I noted in the original post that the series in my data not only vary in the sequences of 1/0s but they also vary in the proportion of 1s and 0s (i.e., the sample variance), just in case this info happened to be relevant to answering the inquiry.

Comment: It's not clear to me the distinction you're drawing in the last sentence. "More variable in its sequence" is clear enough, I think (you seem to mean that $\sum_t (y_t-y_{t-1})^2$ is larger, which it clearly is), but it's then not at all clear what "qualitatively more variable" means if it's intended to mean something other than that. Do you just mean $\text{var}(y)$ - ignoring order, as with an ordinary sample variance - is larger (due to the more equal proportion of 1's and 0's, as you suggest)?

Comment: Yes, ignoring order, there is a more equal proportion of 1/0s which makes it more variable ("qualitative" is just a generic label here), but I am interested in a measure specific to the sequence itself. Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: stated differently, the variation of the *order* or the *sequence* of 1/0s.

Comment: I'll try to clarify again succintly: (1) there is only *one* kind of variation I want to measure and it has to do with the order of 1/0s, *not* the proportion. (2) I brought up the distinction between the order variation and sample variance (as you refer to it) simply to make it known that I am dealing with data that has different proportions of 1/0s if that happens to be relevant to the inquiry. In other words, I'm not only dealing with data like 10001 and 11000 (same sample variance), but also data like 10001 and 11101. Again, I'm interested strictly in the variation in the order of 1/0s.

Answer (score 2):

1. If I have correctly understood, it seems that you can possibly measure it by something like $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{t=2}^n (y_t-y_{t-1})^2$.
2. This measure is also equal to "The number of changes from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1" divided by "the number of times it could possibly have changed" --- i.e. the *proportion* of times it changed from the previous value. (So it's clearly between 0 and 1.)
3. This is also -- up to end effects and possible differences in denominator-correction terms $(1-r_1(y))/2$, where $r_1$ is the lag 1 sample autocorrelation. Since those diminish with sample size, for large samples they should be essentially equivalent.

---

You might also consider a (somewhat) related quantity which is the number of runs in a Wald-Wolfowitz type runs test (many runs = lots of sequential variation, few runs means little sequential variation); note that the number of changes discussed in 2. above is one fewer than the number of runs. However, something based on this measure would condition on the actual number of 1s and the number of 0's (e.g. if there are nine 1's and one 0, then taking that as given, the only possible number of changes are 1 or 2). Consequently if you divide the number of runs by the largest possible number of runs this may be somewhat larger than the above measure (which divides by the total number of changes possible ignoring how many 0s and 1s there were), especially when there is a strong imbalance in the numbers of 1's and 0's.

Comment: This is great, thanks. Are there any references for these measures such that I could look into them further and possibly cite? (not essential, but helpful). I'm going to go ahead and try them in R program.

Comment: Not directly as measures of what you want, at least not as far as I know. I invented 1. just from what you were asking for, saw its connections to 2. (proportion of places that could be changes that actually were) and 3. (relation to autocorrelation), so I mentioned them, then later the connection between number of changes and number of runs occurred to me, prompting the mention of the W-W runs test (prompting a different kind of denominator to 2.). Of course there are references for autocorrelation and runs tests, but neither of those is directly a measure of that thing you asked about.

Comment: If you're working in R, one quick way to do the version in 1. is as follows: $\:$ `seq.var = function(y) {mean((head(y,-1)-tail(y,-1))^2)}`. Note also that you can count the number of runs as `length(rle(y)$lengths)`, so another way to compute it (following the idea in 2.) would be `seq.var2 = function(y) {(length(rle(y)$lengths)-1)/(length(y)-1)}`. However both these functions assume no missing data in your series (which you'd have to think about how to handle if you have any missing values in the middle of a series...)

Comment: Sorry, fixed some typos in those functions. They should be right, now. If you want to standardize the number of runs according to the conditioning in the Wald Wolfowitz (i.e. divide by the maximum runs for $n_0$ $0$'s and $n_1$ $1$'s, you need to compute that maximum (if $n_0\neq n_1$ it's $2\min(n_0,n_1)+1$, and if they're equal, it's $2n_0=2n_1=n$. So that would seem to be `seq.var.ww = function(y) {n0=sum(y==0);n1=sum(y==1);length(rle(y)$lengths)/(2*min(n0,n1)+(n0!=n1))}`

Comment: To help you choose between the first measure I suggested and the runs-test based one, note that with a sequence like 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 the first would take the value 2/9 (two changes where there were 9 places to change), while the second would take the value 1 (with only one "0" there couldn't be more than 3 runs, and the total number of runs was 3, so 3/3=1).

Comment: thanks Glen_b, I can confirm with my data that seq.var and seq.var2 produce the same result, and I also found that the variables produced by seq.var and seq.var.ww are rather weakly correlated (r=-.17). I'll be using both in my exploratory analyses to see how those measures are related to other psychological variables.

Comment: seq.var.ww will range between seq.var and 1. For random binomial variables with p=1/2 and n=10, the correlation is about 0.6; if n=100, the correlation is about 0.8 (and it continues increasing with larger n). To get very weak correlation you'd tend to mostly have very different proportions of 0's and 1's (because that's when they differ more)

Comment: Correct. There is wide variation in the proportions in my data.

Comment: It looks like for general series (not just binary sequences) some references call the first measure the *mean square first difference* (which is what it is; searching on that is how I found them) and some of them look like they'd scale it by the ordinary variance to get a quantity related to the autocorrelation. (one example -- of several I found -- is [here](http://www.maosao.info/pdf/8451844555.pdf), (see p3); also see p697 of *Complex Systems in Finance and Econometrics*
ed. Robert A. Meyers